# Where on the filesystem should a Windows service persist its data?

Tags: windows-services

I'm writing a Windows service which needs to persist some data across reboots/restarts of the service.  Currently I'm writing the files in a directory returned by `Application.UserAppDataPath`, but that doesn't seem to be giving me a consistent answer.  How should I determine the right place to write the data?

Comment: Each service is run with some user's privileges. Shouldn't the data be stored in user's applicationData (I guess you refer to it as Application.UserAppDataPath)? What's the problem with this location?

Comment: The service is running as LocalSystem.  However, the LocalSystem account doesn't have its own directory in "Documents and Settings"; in my tests it uses the LocalService directory but, we're getting reports that the service sometimes stores data in one place and then looks for it in another.  In the registry it seems that LocalSystem's AppData path is %USERPROFILE%\Application Data so it seems that %USERPROFILE% isn't giving us a consistent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if your service is running with the system account or with a specific user account.

- **System** account. Store the files in the CommonApplicationData folder:

  string pathForSystem = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
- **User** account. Store the files in the ApplicationData folder:

  string pathForUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to be consistent (i.e. user agnostic) try `Application.CommonAppDataPath`.

Comment: I agree. If the service is running as LocalSystem then it makes sense to store data in the user-independent data path.

Comment: The Application.CommonAppDataPath is included in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Do i really need reference Winforms from Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a .NET service I think you could use [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)